# Python IDLE - Drag n Drop Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, drag-and-drop, editor, python-idle

Is it possible to drag and drop text in Python IDLE code editor to move or copy text, like you would in say Notepad++ ? This is a Windows installation.

You would think that there would be plethora of answers for this already, but I have come up empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this possible with out of the box IDLE. However this is a feature of the free community edition of [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), check out [this help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/using-drag-and-drop-in-the-editor.html).

Comment: No is correct. I see that same works in Thunderbird and LibreOffice. I do not remember a previous request, but I believe it is possible with tk and tkinter, so have added it to my list of Idle requests.